# How can I find the right resonant frequency of a chassis?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, vibration, frequency-response

Structures have infinite DOFs, so it possess infinite mode shapes. How can we find the right resonant frequency out of the infinite resonant frequencies so that we can save our structure?

For example, if we do vibration analysis in SOLIDWORKS, and we take the first 5 frequencies, it will give us 5 different shapes. In that case:

- How can we make sure that our analysis is right?
- Which frequency out of those five is right?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the **model is adequate and appropriate**, then to answer your second question:

> Which frequency out of those five is right?

All of those modes and frequencies are possible in the structure. Usually the frequencies are provided in increasing order (i.e. the numerical smallest is presented first etc).

The frequency that is *usually* more important, are those that are closest to the **excitation frequency**. This is because eigen frequencies in the structure close to excitation frequency can cause *resonance*.

### a note on "Right and wrong"

regarding the first question:

> How can we make sure that our analysis is right?

I should point out that all the frequencies are "right" and at the same time "wrong".

They are

- **right** because those are the eigenfrequencies that the SOLIDWORKS model has calculated numerically
- **wrong** because the Solidworks model is an approximation of the structure and so you can't really rely on them.

Comment: Suppose Excitation Frequency is 100kHz, and first 5 frequencies of a structure are 25kHz, 40kHz, 50kHz, 55kHz & 60Hz. Now we can say that max frequency of the structure is 60kHz which is less than excitation frequency (100kHz). But how can we prove it, may be if we find 15 frequencies or 30 frequencies, it will match with excitation frequency.

Comment: I would a) check more eigen frequencies (close to the 100kHz) and b) consider the transient effects when starting from rest and going up to 100kHz.

Comment: Excellent Sir, but if we have multiple excitation sources, and we don't know their frequencies (like wind loads, seismic loads), how we can find resonant frequency of our structure then? You have mentioned transient effects, but if we don't know their magnitudes.

Comment: there are methods for taking the spectral content of typical excitation time-series (e.g. for  earthquakes), but to be honest I've never really tried them. In my mind,  in those scenario is very difficult to predict accurately the response, without a physical experiment or at least prior recorded excitation data.

Comment: @Ibrahim Omer ... 100kHz is in the ultrasonic range, far from frequencies in structural applications. I would carefully check whether the structural analysis software is valid for such frequencies ... consider e.g. speed of sound in steel is on the order of 5000 m/s -> wavelength at 1kHz is 5m , wavelength at 10kHz is 50cm etc, wavelength at 100kHz is 5cm

Comment: @PeteW It was just an example, you can take frequencies in MHz.

Comment: fyi MHz is even further away

Comment: @IbrahimOmer PeteW has a very valid point that the frequencies you are are quoting are way high that what would be expected in real life applications. I would be very surprised to see the first frequency over 100 Hz, let alone 25kHz. Also the excitation of 100 kHz is also unexpected as an *mechanical* excitation source.

Comment: @NMech Lets make it 15Hz (Structure). Now it will make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you think should be the frequency of the external force, which will cause it to vibration. If the frequency of the external force is overlapping with any of the natural frequencies, then the structure resonates and you have high amplitude of vibration, which can catastrophically damage the structure.